# Tkinter displaying distorted image

Tags: python, tkinter, gif

I am trying to display a gif using Tkinter, but when the gif loads it looks very odd. I have pasted screenshots of the original gif and the gif displayed in Tkinter. This does not happen with only one gif, but every gif I use.

**Original Frame in Gif:**

[image]

**Frame seen in tkinter:**

[image]

Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import time as t

root = Tk()

frames = []
i = 0

while True:
    try:
        frames.append(PhotoImage(file='display.gif',format='gif -index %i' %(i)))
        i += 1
    except  TclError:
        break


def update(ind):
    if ind >= len(frames):
        ind = 0
    frame = frames[ind]
    ind += 1
    label.configure(image=frame)
    root.after(100, update, ind)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.after(0,update,0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: By the way, the whole gif looks like this, except some gifs have 1 frame or so of correct looking gif.

Comment: Tk's support of animated GIFs appears to be rather fundamentally broken - it only works right if each frame is the size of the full image, which is the most inefficient way of representing an animation imaginable.  (A proper animated GIF only includes the areas that changed in each frame.)  There is some code that claims to work around this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904093/gif-animation-in-tkinter-with-pill-flickering-on-every-other-frame